# GraphQL time complexity with multiple ORs

Tags: time-complexity, dynamodb-queries

I'm querying AWS DynamoDB using GraphQL from my Node.js React app. If I have a GraphQL query that looks like:

```
const variables = {
    filter: {
        or: [
            {authorize_net_profile_id: { eq: 1234 }},
            {authorize_net_profile_id: { eq: 2345 }},
            {authorize_net_profile_id: { eq: 3456 }},
            ...
            {authorize_net_profile_id: { eq: 9999}},
        ]
    }
}
const result = await API.graphql({
    query: listCustomersQuery, variables: variables
});
```

Where authorize_net_profile_id is the primary key
What is the time complexity of this operation? In other words, if my table has N items and I have M elements in my "or" array (see above), then what is the time complexity of my query?

My table is not big enough yet to try running tests so I have not done any tests to determine the answer myself. I expect this to be O(N*M)

Comment: If your table is indexed by primary key, it should be `O(m)` or `O(m log n)` at best